# File manager does not always list alphabetically

Tags: nautilus

Nautilus file manager on Ubuntu 14.04 does not always list document folders in alphabetical order.

When I access my documents normally via the file manager, all folders and sub folders are shown in alphabetical order. But when I try to move a document from the Home folder via right-click and "move to" and then select documents, the folders and sub folders are not shown in alphabetical order. This makes it difficult to locate specific folders and is very frustrating.

Can somebody please explain how I can rectify this problem?

Comment: Try this : nautilus->edit->preferences ->change arrange items default view-> alphabetical order...

Comment: Thanks @Mohammed, but I only find "file manager" which, I believe is the default file manager in Ubuntu 14.04, previously known as Nautilus.  There, I find no options as described by you, i.e. nautilus->edit->preferences->change arrange items - what am I missing here?

Comment: Another specific scenario where this problem occurs is when I want to move a document from my desktop to a file folder in my documents. Right-click>move to>documents takes me to the list of documents in what appears to be random order, not alphabetical.